# How to get the index name of an alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have two indices/indexes named "temp_index_1" and "temp_index_2". Then I add an alias (named "index") to one of them. And now I want to find out the index name for my alias "index". How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.GetIndicesPointingToAlias(Names alias)`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/94ac52a1efd0388c7cf94d10c907501f7560a2fc/src/Nest/Indices/AliasManagement/GetAlias/ElasticClient-GetIndicesPointingToAlias.cs)

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
var indexNames = client.GetIndicesPointingToAlias("index");
```